# Spring Boot 2.0: how to disable security for a particular endpoint

Tags: security, spring-boot, authentication

I need to completely bypass security (authentication / authorization) for certain endpoints in my spring boot 2.0 app--endpoints like "/version" and "/robots.txt"--but keep security in place for all other endpoints.

To complicate matters, I'm working in a project that's a part of a much larger project. My company has another group that has supplied a library that makes use of spring security. This is only relevant because it means I cannot simply override a spring security class to make this work--those classes have already been overridden with code I don't control.

Is there a way to configure spring boot 2.0 to bypass authentication for certain endpoints?

In sprint boot 1.5, we could specify this in our application.yml file:
security.ignored: /version
but in spring boot 2.0 this no longer works.

Comment: try setting `management.security.enabled=true`

Comment: Thanks for the response, pvpkiran.  My understanding is that management.security.enabled configures security for actuators, and not for regular http endpoints.  It was removed in spring boot 2.0. I gave it a try anyway; no luck.

Comment: You will have to configure `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` with an antMatcher like `.antMatchers('/swagger-ui.html').permitAll()`

Answer (score 8):

Federico's answer is correct.  I added the following class to my Spring Boot 2.0 class:

```java
package com.example.demo;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    @Configuration
    public class DemoConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/version").permitAll();
            super.configure(http);
        }
    }
}
```